# Are AWS RDS T3 instances launched with or without the "unlimited" flag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

When I launch an EC2 instance, I have the choice to launch T2/T3 instances with the "unlimited" flag to prevent CPU throttling, but possibly paying a higher cost when I use it over baseline capacity.

Will AWS RDS T3 instances be launched with the "unlimited" flag enabled automatically? I did not find any flag in the UI to enable or disable this option unlike in EC2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Amazon RDS for MySQL Pricing – Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/pricing/):

> **T3 CPU Credits**
>   Amazon RDS T3 DB instances run in **Unlimited** mode, which means that you will be charged if your average CPU utilization over a rolling 24-hour period exceeds the baseline of the instance. CPU Credits are charged at $0.075 per vCPU-Hour. The CPU Credit pricing is the same for all T3 instance sizes across all regions and is not covered by Reserved Instances.